# Break Links in Excel That Contains Specific Word(s) using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to break all links which has a key word in the link. I don't wish to break every link. I've seen VBA where it has to be a full file name in order for it to work, but I was wondering if there's a way to break all links that has only the key words to it?

For example, I have 4 links below. I just want to remove the links with the key words "Brand Site Forecast", removing the 3 links that have it.

Daily Brand Site Flash.xlsx

Brand Site Forecast FY18 (AUG).xlsx

Brand Site Forecast FY18 (SEP).xlsx

Brand Site Forecast FY18 (OCT).xlsx

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:="Brand Site Forecast", Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

But full doc name would like this:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:="Brand Site Forecast FY18 (AUG).xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  Sub BreakExternalLinks()
    Dim ExternalLinks As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim x As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Create an Array of all External Links stored in Workbook
      ExternalLinks = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

    'Loop Through each External Link in ActiveWorkbook and Break it
      For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinks)
    'remove the links with the key words "Brand Site Forecast"
      If InStr(1, ExternalLinks(x), "Brand Site Forecast", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        wb.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinks(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
      End If
      Next x

    End Sub
```

Comment: It's not picking up the links. it skips the IF condition you have since it doesn't match.

Comment: please check updated answer....you can do it by using `Instr` function also

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Maddy for your help! I've changed the VBA a bit and it works perfectly now. Here is the VBA.

```
Sub BreakExternalLinks()

Dim ExternalLinks As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim x As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Create an Array of all External Links stored in Workbook
  ExternalLinks = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

'Loop Through each External Link in ActiveWorkbook and Break it
  For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinks)
'remove the links with the key words "Brand Site Forecast"
  If ExternalLinks(x) Like "*Brand Site Forecast*" Then
    wb.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinks(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
  End If
  Next x

End Sub
```